# Scan for duplicate files with different extensions

Tags: linux, shell-script, text-editing

I am looking for duplicate file names with different file extensions.

Here is the command I run:

```
find -maxdepth 2 -type f \( -name "*.avi" -or -name "*.mkv" -or -name "*.mp4" -or -name "*.mpg" -or -name "*.MP4" -not -name '*~' \) | sort > ~/sorted.txt
```

Here is a sample output (in `sorted.txt`):

```
./Avengers- Age of Ultron (2015)/Avengers- Age of Ultron (2015).mp4
./Beetle Juice (1988)/Beetle Juice (1988).avi
./Clerks II (2006)/Clerks II (2006).avi
./Death Race (2008)/Death Race (2008)-pt1.avi
./Death Race (2008)/Death Race (2008)-pt2.avi
./Death Race 2 (2010)/Death Race 2 (2010).mp4
./Into the Wild (2007)/Into the Wild (2007).avi
./Into the Woods (2014)/Into the Woods (2014).mkv
./Into the Woods (2014)/Into the Woods (2014).mp4
./Pink Floyd  The Wall (1982)/Pink Floyd  The Wall (1982).avi
./The Big Lebowski (1998)/The Big Lebowski (1998).avi
./The Gods Must Be Crazy (1980)/The Gods Must Be Crazy (1980).avi
./The NeverEnding Story (1984)/The NeverEnding Story (1984).avi
./The NeverEnding Story (1984)/The NeverEnding Story (1984).mpg
./Winnie the Pooh (2002)/Winnie the Pooh (2002).avi
```

I want to trim the output written to `sorted.txt` to this:

```
./Into the Woods (2014)/Into the Woods (2014).mkv
./Into the Woods (2014)/Into the Woods (2014).mp4 
./The NeverEnding Story (1984)/The NeverEnding Story (1984).avi
./The NeverEnding Story (1984)/The NeverEnding Story (1984).mpg
```

i.e., the titles that I have more than one copy of. 
Even better would be like this, but the above will do:

```
Into the Woods (2014)
The NeverEnding Story (1984)
```

Note: 
there will be spaces, dashes (`-`), apostrophes (`'`) and parentheses (`(` and `)`) within file names (but no commas (`,`), double quotes (`"`), or underscores (`_`) in file names). 
Also, the final output is for eyes to read, so it does not have to be pretty. 
I just need to be able to manually identify duplicates quickly.

Comment: Wow; *`command `* `|  cat  | ` *`command`* — that `cat` is spectacularly [useless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
rev < sorted.txt | cut -d . -f 2- | cut -d / -f 1 | rev | uniq -d
```

Output:

```
Into the Woods (2014)
The NeverEnding Story (1984)
```

Comment: As you should know by now, Super User prefers answers that include explanations of how and why the commands work.